# get_page() - Only variables can be passed by reference

Tags: pages

When I try to use `get_page()` function I get the error message:

```
Only variables can be passed by reference
```

But what doesn't make sense is that I can use a work around that blows my mind:

## First test

```
$test1 = get_page(49);
```

**Returns error message**

```
Only variables can be passed by reference
```

## Second test

```
$page = get_page_by_title( 'About' );
$test2 = get_page($page->ID);
echo 'ID:'.$page->ID.' Post title: '.$page->post_title;
```

**Returns no error**

```
ID:49 Post title: About
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct to your first test:

```
$id = 49;
$test = get_page( $id );
```

Comment: Cheers, feeling a bit silly right now :)

Comment: @jamiers Do not think about the bad, you are probably tired ..

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the expected behavior of the [`get_page()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page). From the function's codex page:

> $page_id = 123; // 123 should be replaced with a specific Page's id
>   from your site, which you can find by mousing over the link to edit
>   that Page on the Manage Pages admin page. The id will be embedded in
>   the query string of the URL, e.g. page.php?action=edit&post=123.
>
> $page_data = get_page( $page_id ); // **You must pass in a variable to
>   the get_page function. If you pass in a value (e.g. get_page ( 123 );
>   ), WordPress will generate an error.** By default, this will return an
>   object. [Emphasis added]

So just save the page_id as a variable and pass it in (as the other answer suggests).